# Using react-icons package with react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack, font-awesome, babeljs, react-boilerplate

When I install react-icons and trying to import

`import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer';` I get an error

```
Module parse failed: /Users/firfi/work/react-redux-todo/node_modules/react-icons/fa/beer.js Unexpected token (8:12)
```

If I change import to `import FaBeer from 'react-icons/lib/fa/beer';` I get

```
Module parse failed: /Users/firfi/work/react-redux-todo/node_modules/react-icon-base/index.js Unexpected token (3:50)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Reading the error message, I figured out I should change my webpack config.

So I changed exlude statement in

```
{
  test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere with Babel
  loader: 'babel',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  query: options.babelQuery,
}
```

to `exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(react-icon-base|react-icons)\/).*/,`

And now I can `import FaBeer from 'react-icons/fa/beer';`

However, when I use it as  in my render method, it give me an error

`warning.js:36Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of`FaBeer`.`

So how do I get some beer?